# Adding a video to the animating frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

We can add an image to the frame by Adding the image as the background of the `content` but I can't find a solution to add a video using the same approach without a hand. (I just want a frame for my video.)

I want to add an `id` to the added video too.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/rNVLKjr).

And here is exact same code:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
MovieClip();

}, 2000)



function MovieClip() {
  let video = document.createElement('video');
  video.setAttribute("id", "clip"); // Note: add id to video so that we can interact with it later 
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].appendChild(video);
 
  let clip = document.getElementById("clip");

  let source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4`;
  
  /* Adding video as the background of the content not working
  let node = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
  node.style.background = `url(http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4) center/cover`; */

  source.type = 'video/mp4';
  video.appendChild(source); 
   
}
```

```css
/* html {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #121518;
}

video {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 left: 0vw;
 top: 0vh;
 width: 90%;
 height: auto;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 0.1vw dashed #eb4034;


} */

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #11151a;
}

.box {  
 border-radius: 1.31vh;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.box::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0  0.48828125vw, hotpink 0 0.9765625vw) 0 0/1.380859375vw 1.380859375vw;
    width: calc(100% + 1.380859375vw);
    height: calc(100% + 1.380859375vw);
    transform: translate(-1.380859375vw, -1.380859375vw);
    will-change: transform;
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
  }

.box .content {
  width: calc(90vw -  1.953125vw);
  height: calc(85vh - 3.9318479685452163vh);  
  /*border-radius: 1.31vh;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.262vh deeppink, 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin:1vh;
}


@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    will-change: transform;
  }
}


.stopAnimation:after {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 
  
<div id='box' class="box">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Please run the CodePen, I think there is two main issues with my code:

**First:** the video doesn't fill the frame

**Second:** Compare the top corner with the bottom, as you see the lower corner is covered unexpectedly with the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use en element in the same style as a background-image, use the CSS `object-fit` property. When the value is `cover` the element will cover the entire width and height of the parent. Works great for images and video's.

Although this will mess up your ratio. Adding a `padding-top` to the `.content` element with a value of `56.25%` will give you a 16:9 aspect ratio. You can calculate these easily by doing **(height / width) * 100**.

Also since you are practically lazy loading the video, wait for adding the video whenever the `canplaythrough` event has triggered. This event is fired whenever the video has buffered enough to play till the end of the video, with the current speed of streaming data.

The video won't load in the snippet, but if you'll paste this in your codepen or project it works.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  MovieClip();
}, 2000)

const content = document.querySelector('.content');

function MovieClip() {
  let video = document.createElement('video');
  video.controls = 'true';
  video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    content.appendChild(video);
  });
  
  video.id = 'clip'; // Note: add id to video so that we can interact with it later 
  
  let source = document.createElement('source');
  source.src = `http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4`;
  source.type = 'video/mp4';
  video.appendChild(source);
  video.load();
}
```

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #11151a;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 1.31vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, white 0 0.48828125vw, hotpink 0 0.9765625vw) 0 0/1.380859375vw 1.380859375vw;
  width: calc(100% + 1.380859375vw);
  height: calc(100% + 1.380859375vw);
  transform: translate(-1.380859375vw, -1.380859375vw);
  will-change: transform;
  animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
}

.box .content {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(90vw - 1.953125vw);
  
  /**
   * Remove padding and use the height
   * if you don't want to maintain the aspect ratio
  height: calc(85vh - 3.9318479685452163vh); */
  
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  /*border-radius: 1.31vh;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.262vh deeppink, 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), inset 0 0 0.6553vh rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  margin: 1vh;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    will-change: transform;
  }
}

.stopAnimation:after {
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='box' class="box">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any video: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/bGdejGv?editors=1010

Comment: Great Job... Thanks a lot... So many things to learn for tonight...One more question I lost the center aligning (I mean the whole frame is not centered anymore) ... how to fix that...

Comment: The centered alignment has probably to do with the padding exceeding the `100vh` height on the body. But it's hard to say for sure. Changing the `object-fit` value to `contain` makes the video fitting in the `.content` div without distorting its ratio. Also `align-items: center` can make your child element overflow without being able to scroll. Using `display: grid;` and `align-items: center safe;` combats this behavior. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to have a video on top of this box element, you can add `position: absolute` to the video element.

Add this 
  `video.style.position = 'absolute';` after `video.appendChild(source);`

Comment: Please have a look at my updated Codepen and question...I don't want to simply put one above another I just want a frame for my video

Comment: if you want to cover the box element, just add `width:100%` to the video element style. Take note that it will keep the aspect ratio. Or, in your case, `width:calc(90vw - 1.953125vw);` just to match box boundries

Comment: Still, I lose the lower corners of the box.. The video covers the lower frame